# Can't remove RubyGem in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

I ran this command:

```
gem --version
1.3.5
```

I found it to be kind of strange since I didn't specify which gem I was asking about.

I am trying to install the rails gem like this:

gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

But I downloaded the latest gems version 1.7.2 but can't get it to be the system's default version.  Any ideas how to manage this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo gem update --system
```

to update rubygems to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

`gem --version` tells you the version of the RubyGems packaging system.

If you've installed a new version of RubyGems, it's probably been installed in a non-standard location.  It didn't replace the old version of `gem`, and that version is still the one in your PATH.  To run your version, execute it directly or put it in your PATH.

Comment: So is RubyGems a parallel product to RVM, and both are meant to help you manage your gems?